# How to find a sub-document using Mongoose hook without id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find a sub-document using Mongoose hook without 'id';

```
const child = await parent.child.id(id);
```

This code is pretty good but i want to find without **id** (ex: I want to find child match **name**)
Edit:

My code:

```
const parent = await Parent.findOne({name: 'Parent'});
const child = await parent.child.id('5b0068b89f41693d2a71866d');
```

*I got **child.value** // =1*

My data:

```
{  
   "_id":"5b0068b89f41693d2a718664",
   "name":"Parent",
   "child": [  
      {  
         "_id":"5b0068b89f41693d2a71866d",
         "name":"foo",
         "value": 1,
      },
      {  
         "_id":"5b0068b89f41693d2a71866d",
         "name":"bar",
         "value": 2,
      },
      {  
         "_id":"5b0068b89f41693d2a71866d",
         "name":"foobar",
         "value": 3,
      }
   ]
}
```

But I want to get value of **foo**. -> using **name** not **_id**

Thank you!

Comment: So you want either magic or any child?

Comment: I want to find only child match **name** not using **_id**.

Comment: You could put this particularity important detail in you question.

Comment: My advice would be to model your child collection to have the name as it's _id.

Comment: I've already edited. Please help me. Thank all <3